# Using a prefix in MVC routing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I'm trying to set up routing in an MVC app such that an optional language "folder" is at the top level.

e.g.

```
site.com/jp/complexroute
```

... is the Japanese version of the page found using complexroute

```
site.com/complexroute
```

... is the English version of the page found using complexroute

I can think of one way which I think would work which would be to take the entire list of route mappings in RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes and make a second set which are identical but have a language parameter which is constrained to only known language settings.  This sounds like a headache both for writing and maintaining.

I experimented with writing a custom MvcHandler and attaching it to the routes.  This let me extract part of the request and put it into RequestContext.RouteData but by the time this is called it seems that the route / controller have already been picked?

I guess I want something that happens in between the request being received and the route being selected where I can manipulate the url and set a value in RequestContext.RouteData before the lookup against the RouteCollection occurs.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure you will be able to achieve a solution with the method you are suggesting since `RequestContext.RouteData` is not available until after, or possible during, routing.  I don't believe there is an easy way to create a route with an optional parameter in the middle when the parameters after it are required.  Might be easier to always have the parameter present, even in the case of the English version.

Answer (score 0):

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and you can access lang in RouteData.Values["lang"]

sample >

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
internal sealed class DoLocalizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string cultureName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString();
        SpecificCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = SpecificCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = SpecificCulture;
    }

    public CultureInfo SpecificCulture { get; set; }
}
```

and then on each controller you want to be localized apply this attribute

sample >

```
[DoLocalize]
public class AccountController : Controller
```

Comment: Thanks user but my problem is that I don't have a nice controller/action/id route mapping to work with.  I have a large number of custom routes and I'm trying to find a way to map those routes without having to make a copy of all of them with the lang param on the front.